# Assigning SpinUp and SpinDown Macros to a Spinner

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet form spinner that needs to increment a cell value from 1 to 100. The `SpinUp` and `SpinDown` event procedures are housed in the `Sheet1` VBA object, but I can only select one in the **Assign Macro** menu. This means the spinner can only increment up *or* down, irrespective of where I click.

How do I combine the two so the spinner works correctly?

**Please don't suggest using an ActiveX spinner. I have done this successfully, but it has compatibility issues with Mac Excel versions so want to avoid it.**

My spinner is called `Spinner1` and the code in `Sheet1` is:

```vb
Sub Spinner1_SpinUp()
    With Range("A2")
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(100, .Value + 1)
    End With
End Sub

Sub Spinner1_SpinDown()
    With Range("A2")
        .Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, .Value - 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private lngPrevVal As Long

Sub Spinner1_Change()

Dim s As Spinner
Set s = Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Spinner 1").OLEFormat.Object

    If s.Value > lngPrevVal Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Value = "Up"
    Else
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1").Value = "Down"
    End If

lngPrevVal = s.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to declare ```lngPrevVal``` as a private variable?

Comment: It isn't really, just stops it being modified from outside this module.  If you need it accessed from elsewhere then public would be an option.

Comment: If I put ```Dim lngPrevVal As Long``` inside the procedure instead, the spinner only increases, so I'm just wondering why that is?

Comment: Read about variable scope.  In that case,, lngPrevVal is recreated each time the spinner is clicked